# Mandatory field (A or B) in a content type

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, forms

I have a content type (external_document) that has an entity relation to an "event" and an entity relation to a "project."

I would like to be able to have some validation rule saying: All the documents must be "linked" to either an event or a project.

I am unclear on the following:

- How  to do it on D7?
- What is the proper name for that in Drupal so I can search it?
- Is it the "Drupal" way of doing the content type with 2 entity relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Field validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module to take out some of the legwork.

> This module adds an extra tab to each field instance, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your field instances.

There's a validation rule built in for

> Require at least one of several fields

which is exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

**How to do it**

In a custom module, you can implement [hook_node_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) and check whether your condition is met.

If you want to mark the fields as required you could add this with jquery:

```
var requiredHtml = '<span title="Required" class="form-required">*</span>';
$("label[for='edit-field-move-teil-aufenthaltsbewil-value']").append(requiredHtml);
```

jQuery let's you do even more sophisticated things like removing the required mark on the fly from the second entry, if the first one contains (valid?) data.

But remember while jQuery checks can improve usability, they never replace the checks on the server side. Client side checks can always be bypassed by clever users.